# How to interpolate variables within a string using HashMap as variable source

Tags: java, regex, string, hashmap

Let's say we have a string: `string text = "Hello my name is $$name; and my surname is $$surname;"`

It references 2 variables, identified by double dollar sign: **name** and **surname**

We also have a hashmap:

```
HashMap<String, String> variables = new HashMap<String, String>();
variables.put("name", "John");
variables.put("surname", "Doe");
```

How do I replace/interpolate *variables* in a string with their matched Regex values as hashmap keys? (perhaps there's no need to use Regex and Java has this implementation)

In the end, I want variable `string text` to equal `"Hello my name is John and my surname is Doe"`

EDIT: What I meant is replacing the key/variable with the hashmap value without knowing the key. For example, we have a string and we must replace all `$$variable;` values inside in with the `map[variable]`.

What would be the fastest way of replacing this string?

Comment: you can use simple  find/replace. Or go for full-blown templating engines. There are questions how to deal if you have variables missing from your map, how do you output double dollar, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use some regex, parse the input and lookup every key in the Map, like that:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class T2 {
    /** Pattern for the variables syntax */
    public static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\$\\$([a-zA-Z]+);");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Hello my name is $$name; and my surname is $$surname;";
        Map<String, String> variables = Map.of("name", "John", "surname", "Doe");
        String ret = replaceVariables(s, variables);
        System.out.println(ret);
    }

    private static String replaceVariables(final CharSequence s, final Map<? super String, String> variables) {
        return PATTERN.matcher(s).replaceAll(mr -> variables.getOrDefault(mr.group(1), ""));
    }

}
```

Output:

> Hello my name is John and my surname is Doe

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over `variables` and replace the matched keys with the corresponding values without knowing the key using a foreach loop.

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> e: variables.entrySet()) {
    text = text.replace("$$"+e.getKey(), e.getValue());
}
```

Try this:

```
String text = "Hello my name is $$name; and my surname is $$surname;";

Map<String, String> variables = new HashMap<>();
variables.put("name", "John");
variables.put("surname", "Doe");

for(Map.Entry<String, String> e: variables.entrySet()) {
    text = text.replace("$$"+e.getKey(), e.getValue());
}

System.out.println(text);
```

Output:

```
Hello my name is John; and my surname is Doe;
```